# Check the null box if there is no value insert in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

Do you guys have any ideas on how to check null checkbox automatically when we first open the report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the Parameter's Allow Null Value to true then a checkbox will appear that allows a Null selection. If you add a Default Value to the Parameters and set it to (Null) then this box should be checked when the report parameters are loaded in the report viewer.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the Parameter's Allow Null Value to true then a checkbox will appear that allows a Null selection. If you add a Default Value to the Parameters and set it to (Null) then this box should be checked when the report parameters are loaded in the report viewer.

Ok